# Why does my code give the TypeError: TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'?

Tags: python, typeerror, coderunner

I am making a script on Python that you give a string, and it will find the count of the letters in the string, input it into a list, and add up that list. My script runner keeps giving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Untitled.py", line 9, in <module>
countersplit = len(tosplit[counter])
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

My code is as follows:

```
userin = raw_input("Enter sentence: ")
split = userin.split()
tosplit = len(split)
print(tosplit)
counter = 0
countersplit = 0
while counter < tosplit:
    countersplit = len(tosplit[counter])
    wordcount = [countersplit]
    print(wordcount)
    print(countersplit)
    counter = counter + 1
```

What can I do you fix this problem?

Comment: tosplit is an integer and not a list. Thus, you can't use the [] operator on it.

Comment: You set ``tosplit = len(split)``. What do you think ``tosplit[counter]`` means or represents?

Comment: Thank you for the information, and just asking, what exactly can I do to fix this. Should I make a new list name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're trying to achieve.

```
userin = raw_input("Enter sentence: ")
split = userin.split()
word_counts = list()
total_letters = 0
for i in split:
    word_count = len(split)
    print(word_count)
    word_counts.append(word_count)
    total_letters += word_count
print(total_letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of "tosplit[counter]". From your definition "tosplit" is an integer that is equal to the length of "split". Hence you cannot have and index as in tosplit[counter]. For the solution to your problem, is this what you need?

```
from collections import defaultdict
import string
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
string  = input('Enter a String : ')

string = string.lower()

d = defaultdict(int)

for i in string:

    if i in letters:
        d[i]+=1
```